# What's the expansion of $\frac{1}{1+t^4}$ with a last term?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

> Show that when $|x|<1$, $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{(1+t^4)}dx = x - \frac{x^5}{5} + \frac{x^9}
> {9} - \frac{x^{13}}{13}$ .....

The first step of the solution given in my textbook is

$$\frac{1}{1+t^4}=1 - t^4 + t^8 - t^{12}+......+(-1)^{n-1}t^{4n-4}+\frac{(-1)^nt^{4n}}{1+t^4}$$

I don't understand this equation. The binomial expansion gives an infinite series and not a series ending with an $n^{\text{th}}$ term. Where does that last term come from? Is it some form of remainder that includes the sum from the $n^{\text{th}}$ term till infinity?

Also, why can't we just write the normal binomial expansion and integrate it? This seems straightforward but I won't be using the condition $|x|<1$.

What's going on here?

Comment: Let $u\in \mathbb R $ s.t. $|u|<1$. Let $S_n=1+u+u^2+u^3+...+u^n$. $uS_n=...?$ $S_n-uS_n=...?$... So $S_n=...?$

Comment: Do you know formula for sum of a geometric progression? It is just that in action. Put $a=1,r=-t^4$ in $a+ar+ar^2+\dots+ar^{n-1}=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ and split the term on right side as difference of two fractions.

Comment: Your result holds for $|x|\leq 1$ and the solution given in your text is fine. Using the binomial infinite series and integrating it requires more theoretical justification (which is probably at a level higher than your text). Integrating an infinite series is not as straightforward as many cheap textbooks may lead you to believe. Your text instead integrates a finite series and perhaps handles the behavior of integral $\int_0^x\frac{t^{4n}}{1+t^4}\,dt$ directly.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Got it, thanks! I was trying to write the infinite GP form of $\frac{1}{t^4 + 1}$, with $a=1,r=-t^4$. Didn't realize what was needed was the sum of a G.P. with $n$ terms.